# Looking for Monday's Child, young adult horror story

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, horror

The cover of the book, as far as I can remember, was a side view of a girl's face. Black hair, really pale skin, and green eyes.  The cover also had green lightening.  I read it in the mid '90's if that helps.  The book opens when a woman in labor shows up at a walk in clinic after closing, gives birth, and then vanishes off the examination table when the doctor turns around to wash the baby. The little girl is really bad luck to anyone who crosses her;  and turns out to be some kind of dark supernatural entity, who calls herself "a keeper of the Source".  The Source being a black mist type substance she can breathe out and manipulate.  I've been trying to find it for yeas with no luck. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5):

**Monday's Child** by Patricia Wallace. 1989.

One look at young Jill Baker's angelic features seems enough to dispel the rumors about her, but mere coincidence cannot explain the fact that the victims of a series of mysterious accidents were all people who had previously angered little Jill...

For seven years, she had been the Keeper of the Source...

[image]